# Action-on-google local development project, navigate main file to another file

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created simple Action-on google project and build Action with dialogflow.
In Dialogflow Intents are "welcome intent" -> follow-up-yes 
And then fulfillment enabled (firebase http request) with local development project.
in my local project, I'm trying to call anotherfile(app.js) within index.js(The main file)

Plese tell me how to do that?

index.js

```js
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()); 

app.use('/', require('./routes/app'));

const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(app);
module.exports = {helloWorld};
```

routes/app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Welcome-Intent-yes', (conv, param) => {
    conv.close('Plese login ');
});

 router.use(app);
module.exports = router;
```

-------- edited info ------
This is my dialogflow agent with intent 
[image]

output should be coming from my local code. which is

```
app.intent('Welcome-Intent-yes', (conv, param) => {
    conv.close('Please login ');
});
```

i'm not getting any firebse deploy error, but i'm not getting above output from dialogflow.

But if i only use index.js file for my function, then it works and it gives an output from dialogflow

but my requirment is to call another file with my functions inside the index.js file, like what i have done on the above code.

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is - please update your question. Are you getting an error trying to do this? What happens when you try something and what are you expecting? It also isn't clear what you mean by "Intents are "welcome intent" -> follow-up-yes" - posting a screen shot of your Intent may help us understand better.

Comment: I'hv updated my question, please check edited info above. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean just because there is no response shown? Did you click the small arrow on the right of "Default Response"? It is possible that Dialogflow does not show your response by default.